# How can i get the minimum volume?

Tags: android, volume, android-audiomanager

I know that code below is the max volume

```
mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume
```

how can i get the minimum volume?

I used this code but not the minimum volume

```
mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(0);
```

This my code

```
int Minvolume=myAudioManager.getStreamVolume(0);
     int current=myAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
     int volume=(int) (current-1);
            if (current>=Minvolume){
                myAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volume, 0);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
                System.out.println("ADJUST LOWER");
            }
            else if (current!=Minvolume){
                System.out.println("volume is minimum");    
            }
```

Comment: Perhaps try `mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);`

Comment: Has it occurred to you the minimum volume is going to be 0 (zero)?

Comment: No is not zero . volume is going to be 30%

Comment: I really don't understand your question. How can 30% be minimum?

Comment: dear sir thanks for quick replay i want to know how i can used this code( mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(0);) for get volume 0 (zero) stream music  but i my device have sound music i hope you know i what said

Comment: i want while used code my device not sound music but yet have sound

Comment: The `getStreamVolume(...)` method returns the *current* volume of a particular stream. Using 0 in the example you give refers to `STREAM_VOICE_CALL`. All streams can have their volume set to different values. Calling `getStreamVolume(0)` is the same as `getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL)` and will simply return the value that stream's volume has been set to.

Comment: As I said, `getStreamVolume` *gets* the current value of the specified stream - it doesn't *set* it. If you want to set the music stream so it doesn't play use the relevant setter method, i.e., `mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);`. Alternatively, *mute* the stream (turn it off totally) using `mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);`

Comment: i edit my my qustion . looking my code

Comment: i want decrease gradually music stream to minimum but i used this code i have still sound music. i hope you know i what said

Comment: Please re-read my above comment. `getStreamVolume(0)` does **NOT** get the minimum value of anything. The parameter passed to `getStreamVolume(...)` is the stream *TYPE*. In this case, 0 corresponds to `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL` it does **NOT** correspond to a volume value of 0. All your code does is compare the current volume of the music stream to the current volume of the voice call stream and gradually reduces the music stream volume to be the same as that of the voice call stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following to reduce the volume of the music stream...

```
for (int volume = myAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) - 1; volume >= 0; volume--) {
    //
    // add your delay code here
    //

    // Call a method to set absolute volume
    setVolume(volume);
}

private void setVolume(int volume) {
    myAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volume, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to increase or decrease volume would be to use adjustVolume.

```
public void decreaseStreamVolume(int volType, AudioManager am){
    am.adjustStreamVolume(volType, AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
}
```

You can enter AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC or any desirable stream and AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER or AudioManager.ADJUST_HIGHER as per your requirement. I believe it's much cleaner way to execute.