# How to get min volume for a particular stream below API 28?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-audiomanager

I am trying to get min volume using **audioManager.getStreamMinVolume() ** method but its not working below API 28. So, How to get min volume for devices running below API 28 ?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684357/how-can-i-get-the-minimum-volume)